# Material-DataTable disable built-in search

Tags: reactjs, datatable, datatables, material-ui

I'm using npm package material-datatable serverSide true as all action occur (search, sort, filter...) will cause a fetch data from server.

Everything got fine but the built-in search. I want to disable the built-in search feature, because when table search event triggered, it's already fetched the searched data from server and table should only display it (I dont want any local search on this data again). But after research a while, I still can't find a way to disable built-in search.

Anybody know please explain to me, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use `options` to disable it.

```
<MaterialDatatable
  options={
    search: false
  }
/>
```

Comment: It gives error, not complete

Comment: Yes, it works for me if you add double curly brackets, like:

    <pre>
    options={{
      search: false
    }}
    </pre>